# Create an image from a TextView (without losing quality)

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have an app that will create a png image of anything the user write in the text field (custom font and color)

What I'm doing is something like this:

1. Set Typeface, Text Color and Text to a TextView (BG is transparent)
2. Using the code below, generate the image for the TextView

   ```
   Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   //Bind a canvas to it
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
   //Get the view's background
   Drawable bgDrawable =textView.getBackground();
   if (bgDrawable!=null)
       //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
       bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
   // draw the view on the canvas
   view.draw(canvas);

   FileOutputStream out = null;

   out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
   returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
   ```

The problem is that, the quality of the generated image is not the same as what is displayed in the TextView

Is there any way to improve the quality?

Is it because of the TextView not having a background? If so, is there a workaround for this? Need the generated image to only be the text, hence the transparent background

Thanks

Comment: you can take a screenshot
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/3257513

Comment: Try `textview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textview.getDrawingCache());
        textview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);`

Comment: Your size of bitmap depends on width and height of textView which depends (besides from length of text and textSize) on screen metrics. For example, for mdpi you will have 100 pixel height bitmap and for xhdpi 200 pixel height. Does you accept this concept, or you want to return bitmap with strict height (that depends only from textSize)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quality depends on the screen size from you create the image. I suggest you to put the Textview in a FrameLayout and create the bitmap from the FrameLayout..

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
v.draw(c);
return b;
```

}